# InitializeComponent in C# (does not exist in the current context)

Tags: c#, winforms

i have problem with 'InitializeComponent'

Visual Studio writed me: The name 'buttonEDYTUJ_Edytuj' does not exist in the current context.

```
        Controls.Add(buttonDODAJ);
        buttonDODAJ = new Button();
        buttonDODAJ.Text = "Dodaj";
        buttonDODAJ.Click += new System.EventHandler(buttonDODAJ_Dodaj);
        buttonDODAJ.Location = new Point(20, 50);
        InitializeComponent();
```

The following code came from class constructor.

Comment: you are tryin to add the button before you create it; whatever it is that buttonDODAJ contains when you call `Controls.Add` it's not the button you think.

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to the order of the initialization. Instead, the compiler complains that you haven't defined the `buttonDODAJ_Dodaj` handler function in your form:

```
void buttonDODAJ_Dodaj(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // whatever...
}
```

Of course, once you compile it, it won't work as you are adding the control to `Controls` before you create it, and before the component itself is initialized. If this is the real code, it seems that you have somehow managed to reorder the lines.

Comment: I have this metod but it still doesn't work, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You still have the same compiler error? can you show your `buttonDODAJ_Dodaj` implementation and where is it located?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 buttonDODAJ = new Button();
 buttonDODAJ.Text = "Dodaj";
 buttonDODAJ.Click += new System.EventHandler(buttonDODAJ_Dodaj);
 buttonDODAJ.Location = new Point(20, 50);
 Controls.Add(buttonDODAJ);
 InitializeComponent();
```

Add button event as well:

```
private void buttonDODAJ_Dodaj(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```